# React Router How to Display straight Image for Twitter Cards

Tags: reactjs, twitter, react-router, react-router-v4

In my React Single Page Application I am trying to set the value for

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://kareriadventure.in/nature2.jpg" />
```

However the image does not display even though it is sitting in my Public folder.

I have tried to put it in a component and add a Route to it in React Router

```
<Header />
          <div className="container">
            <Route path="/" exact component={Slideshow} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/trekking" component={Trekking}/>
            <Route path="/camping" component={Camping}/>
            <Route path="/homestay" component={Homestay}/>
            <Route path="/services" component={Services}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>


            ***<Route path="/Twittercardimage component={Twittercardimage}/>***

          </div>
    <Footer />
```

However this wraps the image in my header and footer component.

Am I missing something?

I then thought of checking the current route in React Router (But wasnt able to figure out how to do that without getting into State stuff) and putting in an If Then, so if the current route is /Twittercardimage then dont show the Header and Foooter components.

But then I stopped, because this seems like way too much complication to simply link to an image on my website.

How can I set my Twittercard image in a create-react-app simple react application?

This is a very simple functionality. Using React Router I simply want to go to my url/image.jpg and have the jpg appear, without the Header and footer which shows in all other routes as per the above setup.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. Basically I was thinking in terms of the absolute url of the site, however that is not how it is done, a relative URL is required as follows:

```
import TwitterImage from './images/slideshow1.jpg';
import FacebookImage from './images/slideshow2.jpg';

<meta property="og:image" content={FacebookImage} />
<meta name="twitter:image" content={TwitterImage} />
```

Actually this is not really a special case, it is simply how to add an image to create-react-app, which is described here:
[Create-Read_App adding images](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files)

When I do a page view source I get this

So the image is being added perfectly.

How to display a component without a Header and Footer in a one page react SPA, which has a Header and Footer, is yet answered, and is a react -router thing, however since I have solved my problem, I will let that be for now!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using webpack try to import your image such as

```
<img src={require('/foo.jpeg')} />
```

Comment: However to set the Twitter Cards tag, i dont need an image, but a link to an image as follows <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://kareriadventure.in/nature2.jpg" />  So How would I get this link to show an image without getting into React Router? Or is there a simpler way that I am missing? I could get into React Router but then I have the issue listed in my original question.